# "The matter may be kindly taken up" and "The matter may kindly be taken up". Which is correct?

Tags: difference, word-order

> "The matter may **be kindly** taken up"

vs.

> "The matter may **kindly be** taken up".

Which is correct?

Comment: This would not be an idiomatic American English request, for sure. We would not use the passive to make the request in an indirect way, not with **kindly** at any rate, since the adverb applies to the person responding to the request, and the passive leaves that person out of the picture. We would be direct and say "Kindly take this matter up". On the other hand, we could say "The snowflake may be delicately transferred to a chilled microscope slide." since "delicately" applies to the transfer.

Comment: So the original sentence is not grammatically malformed, merely unidiomatic for AmE.

Answer (score 2):

Grammatically neither is wrong.

The difficulty for me, as a native English speaker, is that "kindly" doesn't really fit in this sentence. Its use here sounds very much like "Indian English" - which generally uses correct grammar but unusual word choices.

So, the best way for me to pick the best phrase is to use an equivalent phrase with more "normal" English.

Compare the following phrases:

> 1. The car may be quickly driven
> 2. The car may quickly be driven
> 3. The car may be driven quickly

In most situations, the third of these options (and not corresponding to any options in the original question) is correct. It means that someone may choose to drive the car very fast; the "quickly" applies to the "driven".

In the second option, the word "quickly" applies to "may". This means that quickly (i.e. very soon) it will be possible to drive the car.

The first option means the same as the third option, but sounds archaic, and not how "modern" English is spoken.

Therefore, I'm relatively confident that, using the original words, the best option would be:

> The matter may be taken up **kindly**

But I have to agree with [@djna](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/96182/11145) that the phrase needs rewording completely. Personally I would go for something along the lines of:

> It would be kind of someone to take up this matter

or, less abstractly:

> Please take up this matter

Answer (score 1):

Start with

> The matter may be taken up

I think the intention is to say that it would be kind of some one would take action so the kindness applies to all of **be taken**

> The matter may kindly be taken up

does convey that idea

Whereas

> The matter may be kindly taken up

Could be read as being more concerned about how the action itself is performed

> He kindly helped the boy to his feet

Depending upon the overall context however it is possible that the sentence might be reorganised. Here the feeling is very passive. Somebody may, kindly, take up the matter. If we specifically want a person to do this it might be better to say so.

> It would be very kind of you to take up this matter.